# How to route front-end html files in Web Api 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, url-routing

I have a **WebApi 2** service with front-end built in `javascript/jquery` and pages in pure `html`, i've added those front-end files to my **WebApi 2** project so it will be more easier to bedug and deploy to the server.

All my js files and styles are in `wwwroot` while as the project is built of two "applications" the first one has `html` files in *VMenu folder*, so the next thing i've dove once i've added the `html` files to the project was to create static files route for em and to define the default page of *VMenu folder*.

But here comes the issue... i would to serve the files like routes, like i have three files in *VMenu*, `index.html`, `menu.html` and `expired.html`.

As i've set `index.html` as default when i write `example.com/vm/` i'm able to see the *index* page **BUT** i would the same for `menu.html` and `expired.html`, like to see `menu.html` i would be able just to write `example.com/vm/menu` **instead of** `example.com/vm/menu.html`

But i wasn't able to find nothing more about that type of routing, all projects i've found were razor pages based...

Here is my Startup config:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseDefaultFiles();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseDefaultFiles(new DefaultFilesOptions()
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "VMenu")),
            RequestPath = "/vm"
        });

        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "VMenu")),
            RequestPath = "/vm"
        });

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```